# Android Unknown Text shows on my TextView

Tags: android

Hello I just wrote a simple android application which does receive the username & password from a user when the submit button click and show text in log cat.

however I don't know why the text I insert is shown something like this in Logcat:

> 06-28 14:58:49.061: W/username(858): android.widget.EditText{40cf7a68 VFED..CL ......I. 54,82-264,122 #7f080001 app:id/txtUsername}
>
> 06-28 14:58:49.061: W/password(858): android.widget.EditText{40d02f60 VFED..CL .F....I. 54,190-264,230 #7f080003 app:id/txtPassword}

If you need the code here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    Button btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    
    final EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
    final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
    

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.w("username", username.toString());
            Log.w("password", password.toString());
        }
    });
 }
}
```

what can cause this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shoud use `EditText.getText().toString()`

```
   btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.w("username", username.getText().toString());
            Log.w("password", password.getText().toString());
        }
    });
```

`EditText().toString` returns a string representation of the object.

Comment: You are too quick, my friend :)

Comment: I don't know why i made this mistake but anyways dude you are so fast, haha !

Answer (score 0):

username.toString() returns the string representation of your textview instance named username and NOT the text the user enters. For this you need username.getText()

Hope this helps...